# How to create seperate lists from a list using scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections, scala-collections

I have following list -

```
List((name1,A1,176980), (name2,A2,0), (name3,A3,1948), (name4,A4,95676))
```

From above list I want to create separate lists of list elements like-  element1, element2 and element3 respectively.

I want separate lists like-

```
List(name1,name2,name3,name4)

List(A1,A2,A3,A4) 

List(176980,0,1948,95676)
```

How to get above lists using scala???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive solution:

```
val list = List(
  ("name1","A1",176980),
  ("name2","A20",0),
  ("name3","A3",1948),
  ("name4","A4",95676))

list.map(_._1)    
list.map(_._2)    
list.map(_._3)
```

Some generalize version:

```
def key(products: List[Product], num: Int) = {
  products.map(_.productElement(num))
}

key(list, 0) // res3: List[Any] = List(name1, name2, name3, name4)
key(list, 1) // res4: List[Any] = List(A1, A20, A3, A4)
key(list, 2) // res5: List[Any] = List(176980, 0, 1948, 95676)
```

Or even for product with any arity:

```
def key(products: List[Product], num: Int) = {
  products.map { p =>
    Option(p)
      .filter(_.productArity > num)
      .map(_.productElement(num))
      .getOrElse(None)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you do always have 3-tuples, there's a standard method for this:

```
scala> list.unzip3
res1: (List[String], List[String], List[Int]) = 
 (List(name1, name2, name3, name4),List(A1, A20, A3, A4),List(176980, 0, 1948, 95676))
```

There's also `unzip` for 2-tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> List(("name1","A1",176980), ("name2","A2",0), ("name3","A3",1948))
res9: List[(String, String, Int)] = List((name1,A1,176980), (name2,A2,0), (name3,A3,1948))

scala> res9.map(_._1)
res10: List[String] = List(name1, name2, name3)

scala> res9.map(_._2)
res11: List[String] = List(A1, A2, A3)

scala> res9.map(_._3)
res12: List[Int] = List(176980, 0, 1948)
```